Как сделать чтобы при отправки ссылки вылезала доп инфа [Решено]
Пример:

тоесть я отправил ссылку и высветилась информация

<meta name="description" content="Ваше описание" /> для изображения немного больше кода, но вы можете погуглить как meta image html.

спасибо, помогло)
